# compile folder of cpp files into GNU's g++ using Powershell commands

Tags: c++, powershell, compilation, gnu

I'm looking for a way to pipe a full folders worth of c++ commands into g++ so that I don't have to type 25 file names into the `g++` command.

I am using Powershell and thought that I could somehow use a pipeline with `Get-childItem -Name -Path *.cpp`. That way the whole folder could be compiled at once without the chance of me missing a file or misspelling a filename, and would be modular enough that I could just use `Set-Location folderpath`before pasting it  wouldn't have to write a new makefile each time I make a linked program with a medium~large number of linked files.

Is this possible/practical or should I stick to using a makefile?

For example:
I have a elevator simulation 'borrowed' from a *how to program* book that has 12 header files, 12 classes saved into individual cpp files, and 1 main execution cpp in `C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\ripsfromthebook\ch09\elevator`.

let's assume that everything necessary for the program to work is present and if you typed in each cpp filename into a g++ command it would compile correctly into a working a.exe file.

They are named:

```
bell.cpp
bell.h
building.cpp
building.h
button.cpp
button.h
clock.cpp
clock.h
door.cpp
door.h
elevator.cpp
elevator.h
elevatorButton.cpp
elevatorButton.h
ElevatorSimulation.cpp
floor.cpp
floor.h
floorButton.cpp
floorButton.h
light.cpp
light.h
person.cpp
person.h
scheduler.cpp
scheduler.h
```

It would be great if I could use something similar to `Get-ChildItem -Name -Path *.cpp | g++ -g` to have all 13 `~.cpp` file names be used as an input instead of having to write out this monster {see below} into the powershell commands.

Or using an array of strings to save the childItem output then run g++

```
$x = Get-ChildItem -name -path *.cpp
g++ -g $x -o main
```

would be better than this monster.

```
g++ -g bell.cpp building.cpp button.cpp clock.cpp door.cpp elevator.cpp elevatorButton.cpp ElevatorSimulation.cpp floor.cpp floorButton.cpp light.cpp person.cpp scheduler.cpp
```

short term solution I'm copy/pasting the output of `Get-ChildItem` into my makefile.

Comment: Do you get errors whilst trying to run  Get-ChildItem -Name -Path *.cpp | g++ -g  ?

Comment: yes, here is a copy of what happens in powershell when i do that

`PS C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\ripsfromthebook\ch09\elevator>  Get-ChildItem -Name -Path *.cpp | g++ -g

g++.exe: fatal error: no input files  
compilation terminated.  `

`PS C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\ripsfromthebook\ch09\elevator>  Get-ChildItem -Name -Path *.cpp`
  
`bell.cpp
building.cpp
button.cpp
clock.cpp
door.cpp
elevator.cpp
elevatorButton.cpp
ElevatorSimulation.cpp
floor.cpp
floorButton.cpp
light.cpp
person.cpp
scheduler.cpp  `
`PS C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\ripsfromthebook\ch09\elevator>`

Answer (score 0):

if your are using Cmakelists to build your library/exe you can use file() as below :

`file(GLOB your_src
       "relativePath/*.h"
       "relativePath/*.cpp")
 add_executable(your_exe ${your_src})`

but it seems to be advised against

> GLOB will generate a list of all files that match the globbing expressions and store it into the variable. Globbing expressions are similar to regular expressions, but much simpler. If RELATIVE flag is specified for an expression, the results will be returned as a relative path to the given path. (**We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree**. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.)
>   source: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html#file